# The type or namespace name 'Internal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have created a new C# script in VS Code and when ever I'm starting the VS Code the scripts runs alright in the very first run but, in the second run it shows this error message

> C:\Users\user1234\Desktop\Desktop Folders\My C Sharp\Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Internal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\user1234\Desktop\Desktop Folders\My C Sharp\My C Sharp.csproj]
>
> The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again

I don't understand that it running alright first time but the second time why it's showing this message...

Comment: Don't post only pictures of code or error messages. Post them as the text they are, formatted appropriately. Only post a picture as well if it adds genuine value.

Comment: The error message indicates that the issue is on line 1 of your code but your picture starts at line 2. I don't use VS Code but that seems an odd thing so I suspect that you have actually scrolled the offending line out of view.

Comment: Also it's intellisense is also not working....

Comment: Maybe VS Code is broken. Might be worth reinstalling it and/or your add-ins.